# export oracle tables to sql file fastest way

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to export some oracle tables to seperate sql files without using export function of sqlDevelpper because it takes a lot of times ( 1--> 3 hours per table) is there any way ( command line for example) to export the insert lines to sql file that could be more fast.

thanks.

Comment: read up on expdp

Comment: expdp also includes a parallel option you may want to consider that too